# CMD Batch file Drive letter

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hi Im new with CMD but I'd like to make a few scripts to make my gaming a little easier this might help also in the future.

So I have my code here

```
xcopy /s "D:\MSC\Amistech" "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\Amistech" /Y
```

This works fine for my brothers Laptop but plugging it into my computer gives my USB (D:) (Volume name "120GB") drive a different letter which causes It not to work on other peoples computer I'd like to have it change from the D: drive to auto detect when opened what drive the batch file is opened on but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: I believe you can just leave out the drive letter: "\MSC\Amistech". This will start from the root directory of whatever disk the batch file was run.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, leaving out the drive letter takes the drive of the *current working directory*, which is not the same as the drive and directory where the batch file is located; using `%~d0` in the batch file points to the drive containing the batch file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%~d0` wil give you the drive from where the batch is started

`%~dp0` the complete path.

`%cd%` will give you the path where the program is actually in